# (Processing) I get a null pointer exception when i try to run this code

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null, processing

The program creates 10 squares randomly on the screen, then 10 points, then it uses for loops to compare each point with each square to decide whether or not the point is inside of the square, but whenever I run this code, this line

```
    points[i].x > squares1[j].x && points[i].x < squares2[j].x && points[i].y > squares1[j].y && points[i].y < squares2[j].y
```

returns a null pointer exception, and i can't for the life of me figure out why, can anyone please help.

**Main Code**

```
    PVector[] points;
    PVector[] squares1;
    PVector[] squares2;

    void setup()
    {
      size(800, 800);
      points = new PVector[10];
      squares1 = new PVector[10];
      squares2 = new PVector[10];
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i+= 80)
      {
        squares1[i] = new PVector(random(0, width-80), i);
        squares2[i] = new PVector(squares1[i].x+80, squares1[i].y+80);
        rect(squares1[i].x, squares1[i].y, 80, 80);
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
      {
        points[i] = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
          if(points[i].x > squares1[j].x && points[i].x < squares2[j].x && points[i].y > squares1[j].y && points[i].y < squares2[j].y)
          {
            fill(255, 0, 0);
            ellipse(points[i].x, points[i].y, 5, 5);
            println("Point " + i+1 + " is contained in figure " + j + ".");
          }
          else
          {
            fill(0);
            ellipse(points[i].x, points[i].y, 5, 5);
            println("Point " + i+1 + " is not contained in any figure.");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    void draw()
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace i+= 80 with i++; So only first squares1[0] and square2[0] are initialized. So you are getting a null pointer exception

Comment: In the future, things to do to debug the problem yourself would be to print out the relevant variables before, inside, and after the loop. You'd notice that `i` would be printed only once, and then you could examine why that's the case.